# Is くれてください tautological?

Tags: meaning, honorifics, subsidiary-verbs

I was doing some reading on the different honorific forms in Japanese and came across ください being the humble form of くれる. Does this mean that -くれてください at the end of a request is tautological?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question basically boils down to "yes, this sounds weird and a little redundant."

`くれる` can be used as a normal verb in addition to a subsidiary verb, like

> トムは私に本をくれた

but even then, if you want to request something and use `ください`, the natural way is to just say `本をください`. `くれる` and `ください` have sufficiently different nuances that I don't know if I would call the combination of them *tautological*, but it's definitely not something people typically say - `本をくれてください` sounds at least a little weird.

Similarly, they're not stacked together as subsidiary verbs either. `帰ってくれてください` is at best wordplay and at worst weird/unnatural.