# スーパーに行ったら、牛乳をかってきてくれる？ Why not Te form for Kureru

Tags: て-form

> スーパーに行ったら、牛乳をかってきてくれる？

The Bunpro Translation of the above is:

> If you go to the supermarket, could you buy some milk (and come back)? [for me]

Since we're asking for a favor (it sounds like we are), then why isn't kureru in the Te form?

Answer (score 2):

> 牛乳をかってき**てくれる**?

The pattern is `て+くれる`, which is also applicable to verbs such as あげる and やる.

By using くれる, it's implied that the speaker is requesting a favor, so there's no need to use its て form or to even pair it with ください.

Related: [Is くれてください tautological?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/84146/is-%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84-tautological)