# てくれて for a softened request

Tags: grammar, politeness

Suppose I'm making a casual request, and I want something in between 見てね, which is more of a command and 見てくれる?, which is more of a request. Is 見てくれて natural?

Or maybe I'm looking for something else entirely...

Comment: Related, perhaps? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/92642/9831

Answer (score 2, accepted):

見てくれて is ungrammatical at least as a request. 見て is usually enough. 見てくれ is grammatical but this sounds rather blunt and masculine. 見てちょうだい (an informal version of 見てください) is another option, but it's not very common in real-life casual conversations.

In my opinion, "見てね" and "見てくれない?" are both informal **requests** used between friends and family members. The former is closer to "(Be sure to) watch!" and the latter is closer to "Can you watch?", so the latter is more reserved. Still, a child can safely use 見てね to their parents, and the parents will not feel offended that they were ordered around.

By the way, the following sentence are grammatical as informal requests between friends:

- 見てもらって。
  Have someone watch it (for the sake of you/us)
- 見てあげて。
  Watch it (for the sake of someone).

Comment: Thanks! Two clarifications: is 見て a bit more blunt than 見てね? Also, is 見てもらって grammatical when used on the listener?

Comment: @Riolku 見て and 見てね are equially informal and equally friendly, but the latter has a sense of confirmation ("remember", "be sure", "okay?"). Basaically you can't say 見てね when you say "Look (at that)!"  For the second question, can you elaborate?

Comment: If I ask the listener to look for something for me, and I guess I want to be a bit more blunt, is 見てもらって grammatical?

Comment: @Riolku If there are only the speaker and the listener in the situation, 見てもらって makes absolutely no sense. Think of 見てもらって as "Receive the favor of watching (from him/her/etc)"